# PHP: Keeping times relative forward of a start date

Tags: php, datetime

Stackoverflow,

I need some guidance:

Say I have a list of times `(03.30, 04.35, 05.30, 08.05...23.00, 23.50, 00.36).` Now I know the start date, so for times between 00:00 and 23:59 I can simply use strtotime($time, $date) to get a valid timestamp for the given time. But where I'm struggling to get bullet proof timestamps is when the times move after midnight - using strtotime($time, $date) would give me a timestamp for today, not the following date.

Hopefully that'll make sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

I've done the obligatory search, but I don't think I'm wording my request correctly :(

Comment: Unclear .... Can't understand your question

Comment: Is list always sorted? is the earliest today time is  higher than times of tomorrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i  rightly suppose that the list always sorted and the earliest today time is higher than times of tomorrow, then:

```
$list = array(03.30, 04.35, 05.30, 08.05, 23.00, 23.50, 00.36);

$nextday =  $list[0];
$today = date("Y-m-d", time());
foreach ($list as $item) {
  // need to convert to time format h:i
  $time = str_replace('.',':', $item);
  if ($item < $nextday) echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($today.' '.$time.' +1 day '))."\n";
  else echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($today.' '.$time))."\n";
  }
```

result

```
2015-06-01 03:03:00
2015-06-01 04:35:00
...
2015-06-01 23:05:00
2015-06-02 00:36:00
```

Comment: Spot on @splash58, thanks for your help - both with the problem and translating my dodgy question!